# Increment date based on the time value automatically in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I have a client data which has the candidate id, a start date which will have only the date in varchar format and a time value associated to that date in varchar format in a seperate column.

To give a brief explanation about the data a candidate will come to study center at any time point in a day for example 10:00 AM on 20-10-2014. The start date will be 20-10-2014 and from 10:00 AM he will have test based on the time point. So if the time point is 2 HR, then at 12:00 PM he will have a test. If the time point is 8 HR, it will get added with 10:00 AM and based on this he will have the test at 06:00 PM. When the timepoint reaches 00:00 the start date needs to be the next date instead of 20-10-2014.

The start date needs to be appended with the time value such that when it crosses over the time 00:00, the start date needs to get increased by 1 ie the next day. I have added the start date to the time by using the code below

CAST(STARTDATE as datetime) + CAST(CAST(STUFF([TIME],3,0,':') as time(0)) as datetime) as [EXPECTEDDATETIME]

By this above code i have created the expected datetime however

I will not be able to hardcode the value due to dynamic data. I tried to apply >= and < to the time value something like

```
case when MyTime >= '00:00' and MyTime < '08:10' the Dateadd(day, 1, date)
```

This works perfect but my concern is that I cannot put the value 08:10 because it will not a constant value for all rows.

I have provided a screenshot of my data and a expected date column for reference.

```
Candidate   StartDate   Time    Expected DateTime       Timepoint
1           20141020    1000    2014-10-20 10:00:00     0 HR
1           20141020    1200    2014-10-20 12:00:00     02 HR
1           20141020    1400    2014-10-20 14:00:00     04 HR
1           20141020    1800    2014-10-20 18:00:00     08 HR
1           20141020    0000    2014-10-21 00:00:00     12 HR
1           20141020    1200    2014-10-21 12:00:00     24 HR
1           20141020    1300    2014-10-21 13:00:00     25 HR
2           20141020    1100    2014-10-20 11:00:00     0 HR
2           20141020    1300    2014-10-20 13:00:00     02 HR
2           20141020    1500    2014-10-20 15:00:00     04 HR
2           20141020    1900    2014-10-20 19:00:00     08 HR
2           20141020    2100    2014-10-20 21:00:00     12 HR
2           20141020    2300    2014-10-20 23:00:00     24 HR
2           20141020    0230    2014-10-21 02:30:00     27 HR
2           20141020    1330    ..............
3           20141026    1530    ...............
3           20141026    2000    
3           20141026    0930    
3           20141026    1020    
3           20141026    1120
```

Can anyone help me in this request?

Comment: The question is unclear. Why the 5th row jumps 1 day ahead and not the first? Why the last row on the `Expected Date` column goes from Oct 26 to Oct 21?

Comment: Apart from contradictory and arbitrary data changes (adding 0 to a date shouldn't change anything), you can parse both columns as `date` and `time` and add them to get a `datetime`. Storing dates and times as strings is a very bad idea

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? In SQL Server 2012+ it's far easier to parse strings

Comment: @ZoffDino - The First 6 records belongs to the candidate 1. The first row time is 0000 which is the next day of that candidate. So the date has been incremented to 21 from 20. Also please let me know which part is unclear for you.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I have already parsed the date and time to datetime and that is what I have showed in expected datetime. The only thing i need is when the date crosses over 0000 in each rows the date needs to be incremented to next day

Comment: How do you know the date "crosses over"? Line 1 and 5 have the same values, why should they produce different results? There is no "crossing over" unless you assume that the second time you encounter the same values, some sort of date change occurred. If that's the case, make that clear in the question. Also post the sort criteria and any columns that can help differentiate the rows - otherwise it's impossible to add the extra days

Comment: do you have an additional ID column that can be used to order these records? otherwise it's tricky to perform recursive operations to navigate from row to row.

Comment: I've pretty much written an answer for this but you don't seem to be responding to questions in a timely manner so I'm not prepared to post it unless you respond

Comment: @Tanner - i have edited the sample data to add an column called timepoint.

Comment: @KarthikVenkatraman i don't see any edits to this post?

Comment: @Tanner -- please check now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly this looks like bad data, which probably should have been inserted correctly in the first place with the correct data type (datetime).

You can do what you're after by using a **[recursive cte](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)**.

For this to work with your dataset, I've added an Id column that has been used to order the data, as you can't order by date and time as your data has issues with the date being duplicated for every candidate grouping.

Runnable sample:

```
-- temp table to hold your data
CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
      Id INT ,
      Candidate INT ,
      MyDate NVARCHAR(10) ,
      MyTime NVARCHAR(10)
    )

-- insert the dummy data (with added id for ordering)
INSERT  INTO #Temp
        ( Id, Candidate, MyDate, MyTime )
VALUES  ( 1, 1, '20141020', '1000' ),
        ( 2, 1, '20141020', '1200' ),
        ( 3, 1, '20141020', '1400' ),
        ( 4, 1, '20141020', '1800' ),
        ( 5, 1, '20141020', '0000' ),
        ( 6, 1, '20141020', '1200' ),
        ( 7, 1, '20141020', '1300' ),
        ( 8, 2, '20141020', '1100' ),
        ( 9, 2, '20141020', '1300' ),
        ( 10, 2, '20141020', '1500' ),
        ( 11, 2, '20141020', '1900' ),
        ( 12, 2, '20141020', '2100' ),
        ( 13, 2, '20141020', '2300' ),
        ( 14, 2, '20141020', '0230' ),
        ( 15, 2, '20141020', '1330' ),
        ( 16, 3, '20141026', '1530' ),
        ( 17, 3, '20141026', '2000' ),
        ( 18, 3, '20141026', '0930' ),
        ( 19, 3, '20141026', '1020' ),
        ( 20, 3, '20141026', '1120' )

-- insert data into new temp table, converting values to dates and times  
SELECT  Id ,
        Candidate ,
        CONVERT(DATE, MyDate) AS MyDate ,
        CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(MyTime, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(MyTime, 2)) AS MyTime
INTO    #TempFormatted
FROM    #Temp

-- recursive cte
;WITH    cte
          AS ( 
               -- take the first row
               SELECT   Id ,
                        Candidate ,
                        MyDate ,
                        MyTime
               FROM     #TempFormatted
               WHERE    Id = 1
               -- add next row (look at join: t.Id = cte.Id + 1)
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   t.Id ,
                        t.Candidate ,
                        -- CASE used to compare rows and add a DAY if required
                        CASE WHEN t.MyTime > cte.MyTime
                                  AND t.Candidate = cte.Candidate
                             THEN cte.MyDate
                             WHEN t.MyTime < cte.MyTime
                                  AND t.Candidate = cte.Candidate
                             THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, t.MyDate)
                             ELSE t.MyDate
                        END AS MyDate ,
                        t.MyTime
               FROM     cte
                        INNER JOIN #TempFormatted t ON t.Id = cte.Id + 1
             )
    -- output from cte
    SELECT  cte.Id ,
            cte.Candidate ,
            cte.MyDate ,
            cte.MyTime ,
            CONVERT(DATETIME, cte.MyDate) + CONVERT(DATETIME, cte.MyTime) FormattedValue
    FROM    cte

-- tidy up
DROP TABLE #Temp
DROP TABLE #TempFormatted
```

Comment: Hi Tanner, Awesome... U solved my problem... thanks a lot... I dont know why people have down voted my post... Is the requirement not clear?